# Find the named ranges a given cell belongs to

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a personal macro that displays important info about the ActiveCell on the statusbar, like the names (if any) of tables or pivottables it belongs to, what *unformatted* value it holds and such.

Now I would also like to display the names of the named ranges the cell is included in. I guess I could scan through some Names Collection for the ActiveWorkbook and test with intersect, but is there any easier way?

Comment: If the Named Range only includes the ActiveCell then ActiveCell.Name.Name will return the Named Range.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, thats useful, but already exploited I guess in Excel's adress window (up on the left).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to loop through the names.

```
Function getRangeNames(Target As Range)
    Dim n As Name
    Dim s As String
    For Each n In ThisWorkbook.Names
        On Error Resume Next
        If Not Intersect(Target, n.RefersToRange) Is Nothing Then
            s = s & n.Name & ", "
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next n

    getRangeNames = Left(s, Len(s) - 2)
End Function
```

Comment: Of course it is, and if anyone might come, the question may be relevant too?

Comment: @MLind I agree.   By the way, I like your concept.

Comment: It's nothing fancy, a class module in the personal workbook with Appl_SheetSelectionChange calling a subroutine writing info about the current cell at the left of the statusbar much the same way as Excel 2010 writes range sums to the right of the bar. Maybe I could share it here somehow? It's only like two screenpages of code.

Comment: Could you email it to me? tommy70458@gmail