# Interrupt macro to process keystrokes for smooth user experience

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, keyboard-events

I'm working on a macro that displays cell info on the statusbar on each selection change within the excel application. [It has grown with the addition of new features thanks to help from members in here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740233/find-the-named-ranges-a-given-cell-belongs-to) So now sometimes the focus sticks to a cell and I cant move on with the arrow keys to nearby cell before the cell info to be displayed has been calculated. But I do want the selection to move on for a smooth user experience. How should I interrupt the calculation?

It goes something like this in a class module:

```
Private Sub Appl_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim InfoAboutTarget 
    InfoAboutTarget = GetInfoAbout(Target)
    WriteInfoToStatusbar(InfoAboutTarget)
End Sub
```

Is any of the following two options any good?

1. Have an application_onkey event raising an error flag with a user-defined error code and an error handler in the above sub that exits on this particular error
2. Measure the time elapsed since the above sub started at interesting points in the code and exit after a time large enough to threaten the user experience?

Comment: For each "part" and also each "loop" you could pack an `DoEvents`. This would slow down the macro, but you could still interact. Checking for the actual address and stuff like that (would slow down even more), simply kill the execution if it has been changed. Having events which Restart a new calculation should not be affected... you will notice a delay in getting your "info" but should be able to interact with the application like no code is running...

Comment: Manual says "DoEvents passes control to the operating system. Control is returned after...". But I don't want it to be returned, I want it execution of the sub to stop.

Comment: Manual also says "Any time you temporarily yield the processor within an event procedure, make sure the procedure is not executed again from a different part of your code before the first call returns; this could cause unpredictable results. ..." but I feel the code cannot fulfil this as new selection change events will trigger new execution of the sub

Comment: for this reason check the input like "is the selection the same like when the calculation started?" And if not -> `End Sub`. Depending on the included subs/functions you may go with a global variable and a private variable for each sub/function. Each time a new cycle of the whole process is started, the global variable is set to processor time. Inside the sub/function set the private variable to the global one and if it is not 0, then check if it is equal to it. If not, a new cycle has been started and thus the old can be killed with `Exit Sub/Function`

Comment: Like after each `DoEvents` put `If globalVar <> privateVar Then Exit Sub`. Even if one sub is executed several times, every instance will have their own private variable. As long as new instances are running, the old ones will be at halt, but after finishing the newest one, all other should terminate itself... if you get my point here ;)

Comment: To my eye the cpu-timer may be the best solution, because going from A1 to A2 and back to A1 may kill the A2 calculation after finishing A1. But the second A1 may be finished too. Still, everything depends on the code you have right now... it may be easy or nearly impossible...

Comment: @Dirk Reichel I swear I saw your comment after I posted my answer xD

Comment: @DirkReichel Great job and so fast! Many thanks! After having run Chris' code I do no longer worry about the cautions in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dirk says, you should use `DoEvents` to allow excel to process user input, *and* detect if you long running code is interrupted and if so, cancel the interrupted execution, while allowing the most recent call to complete.

Here's an example to demonstrate (coded in `ThisWorkbook`)

```
Option Explicit

Dim abort As Boolean
Dim CallCount As Long

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    test Target
End Sub


Sub test(r As Range)
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, b As Long

    CallCount = CallCount + 1
    n = 100
    ' simulate long running code
    For i = 1 To n
        DoEvents
        If abort Then
            GoTo AbortSub
        End If
        Application.StatusBar = CallCount & " " & r.Address & " " & i
    Next
AbortSub:
    ' Abort all interrupted calls
    If CallCount > 1 Then
        abort = True
    Else
        abort = False
    End If
    CallCount = CallCount - 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks, works like a charm and explains it all! Maybe just a tiny bit easier to understand if you now if boolean automatically initiates to false and long to 0, i'll  try to edit that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work, but maybe something like this

```
Dim globalCounter As Long ' 0 by defaul

Private Sub Appl_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    globalCounter = globalCounter + 1
    WriteInfoToStatusbar GetInfoAbout(Target)
End Sub

Function GetInfoAbout(Target As Range)
    Dim localCounter As Long 
    localCounter = globalCounter 
    ' .. some code
    DoEvents
    If localCounter <> globalCounter Then Exit Function
    ' .. some code
End Function
```

Comment: Right idea, but doesn't work, because the counters get updated on the each call so are always equal

Comment: @chris neilsen even if the counter is in a separate module? maybe a cell can be used to store the count instead